# Get TaxonomySession TermStore TermSet Term from Sharepoint 2010 Server using Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll

Tags: sharepoint-2010, client, taxonomy

I'm coding a c++/c# client-application to communicate with a Sharepoint 2010 site which uses Taxonomy
 
I have downloaded and installed Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll from:
http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/1/9/E1987F6C-4D0A-4918-AEFE-12105B59FF6A/sharepointclientcomponents_x64.msi

The client user may enter values in a form by selecting values from a dropdown of values collected from a Taxonomy TermSet. In order to fetch the TermSet I must first get a TaxonomySession:

```
TaxonomySession taxonomySession = TaxonomySession.GetTaxonomySession(clientContext);
clientContext.Load(taxonomySession, 
    ts => ts.TermStores.Include(
    store => store.Name,
    store => store.Groups.Include(
    group => group.Name))
);
try
{
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    string err = e.Message; // Cannot find proxy for type with id "{981cbc68-9edc-4f8d-872f-71146fcbb84f}"
}
```

I'm uncertain whether the reason is that it is illegal to use Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll (Sharepoint 2013) against a Sharepoint 2010 server or whether I'm doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

The use of the Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll (Sharepoint 2013) against a Sharepoint 2010 server will only render errors.

There is one service side dll for sharepoint 2010 (Microsoft.Sharepoint.Taxonomy.dll), but then you have to be on one sharepoint machine in the farm. (Requires .NET 3.5 I think, won't work in .NET 4.0)